# How do I send a make an ajax call when on every page request and make changes to the DOM with the results of the ajax call?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension that will make an ajax call each time the user loads a new url in their browser. When the results of that ajax call come in I would like to make changes to the DOM with the results of the ajax call. I am still new to chrome extension development but from what I've read it is best to make the ajax call in the background script then send the results to the content script where it can modify the DOM.

I am able to make the ajax call and get the results in the background.js but when I try to send it to popup.js I don't get an alert with the data, which I need so I can modify the DOM.

I have:

*background.js*

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  process,
  {urls: ["*://www.example.com/*"]},
);

function process(details){ 
  var xhr;
  xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", "https://example2.com/", true);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
      return myCallback(xhr.responseText);
    }
  };
  xhr.send();

  chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.removeListener(getDeals);
  return
}

function myCallback(resp){
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    data: resp
  });
}
```

*popup.js*

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(data) {
    alert(data);
  }
);
```

*manifest.json*

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "My program",
  "description": "my description",
  "version": "1.0",

  "icons": {"16": "daisy_16.png",
           "48": "daisy_48.png",
          "128": "daisy_128.png"},
  "permissions": [
    "background", "webRequest","webRequestBlocking", "webNavigation", "tabs", "https://example2.com/*", "declarativeContent", "storage", "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "externally_connectable": {
    "matches": ["*://*.example2.com/*"]
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
    "js": ["jquery-3.4.1.min.js", "popup.js"],
    "run_at": "document_end"
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send a message to a tab you need [chrome.**tabs**.sendMessage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-sendMessage) with a `tabId` and `frameId` so let's pass `details` to myCallback and use it inside:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  process,
  {urls: ['*://www.example.com/*']},
);

function process(details) {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', 'https://example2.com/');
  xhr.onload = () => myCallback(xhr.responseText, details);
  xhr.send();
}

function myCallback(data, {tabId, frameId}) {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {data}, {frameId});
}
```

This code is assuming you're running a content script in each iframe, not just in the main page:

```
 "content_scripts": [{
    ...........
    "all_frames": "true"
  }]
```

Otherwise use `0` to send to the content script of the main page only:

```
function myCallback(data, {tabId}) {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {data}, {frameId: 0});
}
```

Comment: In popup.js I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onMessage' of undefined"

Comment: The error message tells that chrome.runtime is undefined which cannot happen in a content script, meaning you're doing something really weird there so it should be described in detail. This error is not related to anything in this answer so you should probably open a new question.